# Angular 2 Template Form

Tags: angular-ui-router, angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I have a template-driven Login form and below/outside my form there is a button for "forgot password".

Whenever I click on the "forgot password" button, it first validates my form then at the next click, it navigates.

{{'userNameRequired' | translate}}
        
        
          {{'userName should between 8-15 letters and contain alphabet, digits and special character like _ , -, . ' | translate}}
        
      
      
        
      
      
        
          {{'passwordRequired' | translate}}
        
        
          {{'Password must be of a Capital Letter, alphabets and special character like @ and _' | translate}}
        
      
      
        
          {{'login' | translate}}

```
<p style="text-align: center; ">
  <a [routerLink]="/forgotpassword">Forgot Password</a>
</p>
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue that you're facing here?

Comment: I directly want to navigate to my forgot password page whenever i click on the forgot passowrd button.

Comment: Please provide a sample of what has already been done

Comment: Is your "forgot password" link is placed inside the <form> container ? May be that creates the issue.

Comment: no it's outside the form container

Comment: can you please put your login form code...so will get clear about your issue.